# e.ProgressPercentage returns 0-50

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp, webclient

I have the following code that monitors the upload process. I'm using `e.ProgressPercentage` to keep track of the current progress, but it's returning wrong values.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(DataIO.FTP.Username, DataIO.FTP.Password);

    Uri uri = new Uri($"ftp://{DataIO.FTP.Server}/{DataIO.FTP.UploadDir}/{DataIO.SelectedOutputArchive}.tar.gz");

    client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(delegate (object s2, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e2) {

        ProgressLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ProgressLabel.Text = $"{(e2.BytesSent / 1024).ToString()} KB / {(e2.TotalBytesToSend / 1024).ToString()} KB";
        });

        UploadProgressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            UploadProgressBar.Value = e2.ProgressPercentage; // returns 0-50
            //UploadProgressBar.Value = (int)Clamp((float)e2.ProgressPercentage / 50 * 100, 0, 100);
        });

        Debug.WriteLine(e2.ProgressPercentage);
    });

    client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(delegate {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.Text = "Upload: Success";
        });

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.Close();
        });

    });

    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", localFilePath);
}
```

I tried debugging it in the output window and the values it returned were like this:

```
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
1
2
2
1
2
2
3
3
2
3
3
...
49
49
50
49
100
49
49
```

These back jumps are not necessarily important but jumping from 49 to 100 is.

I assumed that it always returns between 0-50 (after realizing that it doesn't to up from 50). So I needed to scale it to 0-100. This worked, but then it jumped from 49 to 100. Scaling expects numbers from 0-50, and receiving 100 breaks it (results in overflow (200), progressbar expects 0-100). Then I had to clamp the result value. So I came up with this:

```
(int)Clamp((float)e2.ProgressPercentage / 50 * 100, 0, 100)
```

While this works fine now, I'm wondering why I need to hack my way to make it work. Am I doing something wrong?

---

**Update**: I have decided not to rely on `e.ProgressPercentage` and do the calculation myself:

```
UploadProgressBar.Value = (int)(e2.BytesSent / (float)e2.TotalBytesToSend * 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The reason is

> when you do an upload the server can also send data as a response to the upload. In general this is true for any HTTP Request. Consider a form uploading a bunch of input and the server sending a whole bunch of data, perhaps an SQL server database report. 
>   In all these cases we divice the upload and download to 50% and 50%. 
>   So if the server is not sending any data then it will jump from 50 to 100 directly

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ab5a1b4-c30d-4dbb-bebe-a00ef8e72029/problems-with-webclientuploadfileasync?forum=netfxnetcom

Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420983/webclient-uploadfileasync-strange-behaviour-in-progress-reporting) for possible issues with this approach.

**Another solution**

Another option for visualizing the correct values of your upload is to use another two properties of the UploadProgressChangedEventArgs object - BytesSent, TotalBytesToSend - and make the calculation yourself. For reference, check [the examples section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

EDIT:
I could not find anywhere documented what is the reason of implementing this in such manner, but here is the code that is responsible for this behavior:

```
        private void PostProgressChanged(AsyncOperation asyncOp, ProgressData progress) {
        if (asyncOp != null && progress.BytesSent + progress.BytesReceived > 0)
        {
            int progressPercentage;
            if (progress.HasUploadPhase)
            {
                if (progress.TotalBytesToReceive < 0 && progress.BytesReceived == 0)
                {
                    progressPercentage = progress.TotalBytesToSend < 0 ? 0 : progress.TotalBytesToSend == 0 ? 50 : (int)((50 * progress.BytesSent) / progress.TotalBytesToSend);
                }
                else
                {
                    progressPercentage = progress.TotalBytesToSend < 0 ? 50 : progress.TotalBytesToReceive == 0 ? 100 : (int) ((50 * progress.BytesReceived) / progress.TotalBytesToReceive + 50);
                }
                asyncOp.Post(reportUploadProgressChanged, new UploadProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, asyncOp.UserSuppliedState, progress.BytesSent, progress.TotalBytesToSend, progress.BytesReceived, progress.TotalBytesToReceive));
            }
            else
            {
                progressPercentage = progress.TotalBytesToReceive < 0 ? 0 : progress.TotalBytesToReceive == 0 ? 100 : (int) ((100 * progress.BytesReceived) / progress.TotalBytesToReceive);
                asyncOp.Post(reportDownloadProgressChanged, new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, asyncOp.UserSuppliedState, progress.BytesReceived, progress.TotalBytesToReceive));
            }
        }
    }
```

Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs.html#2966

Comment: It does not explain the drop though.

Comment: Is this design/behavior documented? I'd like to read more. Also, I've decided to calculate the percentage myself for now. It's much cleaner.

Comment: I edited my previous answer and include a URL for code reference (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs.html#2966). Unfortunately, though, I could not find any documentation on why this is working as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same, including the strange drop.

Consider using `FtpWebRequest` from a separate thread instead. That way, you have a full control of the upload progress.

See my answer to 
[How can we show progress bar for upload with FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6341024/850848#45931971).